# admin queryset function for more than one ModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-admin

In my admin.py I have:

```
class SayfaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(SayfaAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        ....
```

But, instead of defining same queryset function, I wish to write a function which will be called within admin class and returns the result so, instead of writing something as above, I wish to write:

```
class SayfaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = somefunc()

def somefunc():
    ...
    return somevalue
```

My problem is, how can I get modelAdmin class (SayfaAdmin in my example), so I can call the function with parameters (request, self and modeladmin) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you call it with `self`?

```
def queryset(self, request):
   return somefunc(self, request)



def somefunc(obj, request):
    ...
```